# Web Socket Beast client vs Spring boot web socket server

Tags: websocket, beast

I am trying to do basic web socket programming with Spring boot as a web socket server and C++ Boost(Beast) as a web socket client. I can able to write sample programming and able to do connection between this server and client but could not succeeded on text transfer between server & client.

I can run successfully from browser sample client using js but I could not succeed from C++ Boost lib since I am new to this.
async_write & async_read function is failing and not sending/received data from server. But it is able to connect to web socket created by spring boot app.

*Spring boot web socket server:*

---

### --- Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/websocket-example");
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/websocket-example").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

---

### --- Controller

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @MessageMapping("/user")
    @SendTo("/topic/user")
    public UserResponse getUser(User user) {

        return new UserResponse("Hi " + user.getName());
    }
}
```

---

### --- C++ Boost client

```
// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream> ws_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
    std::string host_;
    std::string text_;

public:
    // Resolver and socket require an io_context
    explicit
        session(net::io_context& ioc)
        : resolver_(net::make_strand(ioc))
        , ws_(net::make_strand(ioc))
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
        run(
            char const* host,
            char const* port,
            char const* text)
    {
        // Save these for later
        host_ = host;
        text_ = text;

        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(
            host,
            port,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_resolve,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
        on_resolve(
            beast::error_code ec,
            tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "resolve");

        // Set the timeout for the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(
            results,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_connect,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
        on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type ep)
    {
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
        // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
            websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                beast::role_type::client));

        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::request_type& req)
            {
                req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                " websocket-client-async");
            }));

        // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
        // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
        // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
        host_ += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/websocket-example",
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_handshake,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
        on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "handshake");

        // Send the message
        ws_.async_write(
            net::buffer(text_),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_write,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
        on_write(
            beast::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_read,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
        on_read(
            beast::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        // Close the WebSocket connection
        ws_.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_close,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
        on_close(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "close");

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully

        // The make_printable() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer_.data()) << std::endl;
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        std::cerr <<
            "Usage: websocket-client-async <host> <port> <text>\n" <<
            "Example:\n" <<
            "    websocket-client-async echo.websocket.org 80 \"Hello, world!\"\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto const host = argv[1];
    auto const port = argv[2];
    auto const text = argv[3];

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    std::make_shared<session>(ioc)->run(host, port, text);

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the socket is closed.
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Your suggestion will help me to check the Boost client part.